# Google Map Autosuggest - Trigger Geocode on click of autosuggest

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently when you click on the autosuggest suggestion in the location field it just loads it into the input box. I want to make an adjustment to it, so when you click on the result in the autosuggest box, not only does it load its value into the input box but it also triggers the geocode. I cant get my head around how I would do this though, so I would appreciate some help.

This is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/njDvn/130/

```
<!-- Geocode -->
$(document).ready(function () {
    var GeoCoded = { done: false };
    autosuggest();
    $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (GeoCoded.done) return true;

        e.preventDefault();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById('location').value;

        $('#myform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);

        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        },

        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
                $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                GeoCoded.done = true;
                $('#myform').submit();
            } else {
                console.log("Geocode failed: " + status);
                //enable the submit button
                $('#myform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
            }

        });

    });

});
```

And the autosuggest:

```
<!-- AutoSuggest -->
function autosuggest() {
    var input = document.getElementById('location');
    var options = {
        types: [],
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do instead is use only Places API library and simply listen for `place_changed` event like in this sample here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#getting_place_information

You can get the Geocode using: `place.geometry.location`

Comment: So how does this work? place_changes triggers as soon as the value in the input box changes? This might make it more complicated.

Comment: The service fires a place_changed event when a user selects a Place from the predictions attached to the text field. It should make it simpler - you don't need to make a new request with the geocoder because the information is already there :)

Comment: Would you be kind enough to show how this would work with the code I have already?

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect except! It no longer geocodes if you dont click on an autocomplete suggestion. For example, if I type in "London" but dont click on the google autocomplete suggestion of "London, UK" then it doesnt geocode. I want it to work for both scenarios. Is this possible with your code? It does one bit perfectly!